# Strange behavior when rendering two instances of react component

Tags: reactjs

I have a component that is essentially a table view with rows and columns each row has an edit button, when I click the button it should populate the value of each row this is my goal of the component. Also, I have to render two instances of this component on the same page. The strange thing is when I click on the edit button in the first table, it populates the correct value, but when I click on the second table, it always populates the value of the first table. Moreover, if I console.log the value of the second table, it shows the correct value.

```
//Here the instances of the component
<TabelSection numberOfRow={5} roleAreaArray={roleAreaArray} roles='Roles' />
<TableSection numberOfRow={3} modeTypeArray={modeTypeArray} modes='Modes' />

//Table component
export default function TableSection({ numberOfRow, roleAreaArray, modeTypeArray, roles, modes }) {

  const [modalData, setModalData] = useState({
    modalType: '',
    holder: ''
  })
  const { modalType } = modalData
  const openModalWithItem = useCallback((holder, modalType) => {
    setModalData((preData) => {
      return {
        ...preData,
        modalType,
        holder,
      }
    }
    )
  }, [])

  const onChangeHandler = (event) => {
    const name = event.target.name;
    const value = event.target.value;
    setModalData({
      ...modalData,
      [name]: value
    })
  }
  console.log("securityModal", modalData.holder)
  return (
    <>
      <MyModal modalData={modalData} setModalData= 
       {setModalData} onChangeHandler={onChangeHandler} />
      <table className='table  table-sm '>
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th scope='col'>{roles ? roles : modes}</th>
            <th scope='col'></th>
            <th className='pointer' scope='col' data-toggle="modal" data-target="#secuirtySectionModal">
              <i className="fas fa-plus fa-xs text-success "></i>
              <span className='text-success '>New</span>
            </th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          {
            [...Array(numberOfRow)].map((_, index) => (
              <TableRow
                key={index}
                index={index}
                areaArray={roleAreaArray?.length > 0 ? roleAreaArray : 
                 modeTypeArray}
                openModalWithItem={openModalWithItem}
              />
            ))}
        </tbody>
      </table>

// TableRow Component
export default function TableRow({ index, areaArray, openModalWithItem }) {
    let holder = areaArray[index]
    return (
        <tr>
            <td scope="row">
                <span className='font-weight-normal ml-3'>{index + 1}</span>
            </td>
            <td scope="row">
                <span className='font-weight-normal'>{holder}</span>
            </td>
            <td>
                <i onClick={() => openModalWithItem(holder, 'editModal')}
                    className="fas fa-pencil-alt ml-3"
                    data-toggle="modal"
                    data-target="#secuirtySectionModal">
                </i>
            </td>
        </tr>
)
}
//Modal Component 

export default function MyModal({
    modes,
    roles,
    activeItemId,
    onChangeHandler,
    modalData,
    setModalData
}) {
    const { holder } = modalData
    const [addSolution] = useAddSolutionMutation()
    const [updateSolution] = useUpdateSolutionMutation()

    const apiCall = () => {
        if ('' === 'addModal') {
            //NOTE: make add API call 
            console.log('ADD API call')
            //addSolution(activeItemId)

        } else {
            //NOTE: make Edit api call 
            console.log('Edit API call')
            //editSolution(activeItemId)
        }
    }
//Here gives me the correct value but does not update input value
    console.log('modal', holder)
    return (
        <div className="modal fade blueText" id='secuirtySectionModal' tabIndex="-1" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
            <div className="modal-dialog">
                <div className="modal-content">
                    <div className="modal-header">
                        <h5 className="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">{roles ? roles : modes}</h5>
                        <button type="button" className="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                            <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                        </button>
                    </div>
                    <div className="modal-body">
                        <form>
                            <div className="form-group">
                                <label htmlFor="accessBy" className="col-form-label">Role:</label>
                                <input id="accessBy" name='holder' type="text" className="form-control" value={holder} onChange={onChangeHandler} />
                            </div>

                            <div className='d-flex'>
                                <div className='flex-grow-1 mr-3'>
                                    <label htmlFor="role" className="col-form-label">Number:</label>
                                    <select id='role' name='role' className="form-control" onChange={onChangeHandler}>
                                        <option className="dropdown-item" ></option>
                                        <option className="dropdown-item" value="1">1</option>
                                        <option className="dropdown-item" value="2">2</option>
                                        <option className="dropdown-item" value="3">3</option>

                                    </select>
                                </div>

                            </div>
                        </form>
                    </div>
                    <div className="modal-footer">
                        <button type="button" className="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal" >Cancel</button>
                        <button onClick={apiCall} type="button" className={`btn btn-success`}> Save Changes</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    )
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you are using the same modal component to edit the values. Reset the state values on modal open and close events. Can give a more comprehensive answer if you can share the code

Comment: Correct I am using a modal,

Comment: would you mind sharing your code?

Comment: Sure, I edit my post with all code. thanks